# zlib.output_compression - for zip functionality it should be On or Off

Tags: php

What is significance of `zlib.output_compression` in zip functionality?

Should it be on or off?

Do I have to add ContentType gzip

Should the extension of generated file should be `.gz` instead of zip.

Which is the best way of zipping a bunch of files, huge number of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zlib.output_compression is only for compressing text data for the browsers to reduce the traffic, it can not be used to generate zip files.

You should use an appropiate library to do that severside and then stream the zip to the client with the correct mime type header, then the browser will ask the user to store the file as an usual download.

Comment: ok so i dont have to use  zlib.output_compression  at all. !!

Comment: no, you need to use Zip functions to do that: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Answer (score 1):

zlib.output_compression will "swtich on" the gzip functionality. It will compress the pages if the end user browser tells apache that "yeah, bring "gzip" on" !!

Keep the zip level to -1.. I think the directive is `zlib.compression_level`